# How to use requirejs to work with ajax callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, requirejs

If I have to leverage niceties of jQuery AJAX API and set my own custom settings for each ajax call my app makes like below:

Say I have a page which displays employee information within table by making ajax calls to some API.

```
define(["jQuery"], function($) {
    var infoTable = function (options) {

        function init() {
            // Provide success callback
            options.success_callback = "renderData";
            getData();
        }

        function renderData() {
            // This callback function won't be called as it is not 
            // in global scope and instead $.ajax will try to look 
            // for function named 'renderData' in global scope.
            // How do I pass callbacks defined within requirejs define blocks?
        }

        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: options.apiURL,
                dataType: options.format,
                data: {
                    format: options.format,
                    APIKey: options.APIKey,
                    source: options.source,
                    sourceData: options.sourceData,
                    count: options.count,
                    authMode: options.authMode
                },
                method: options.method,
                jsonpCallback: options.jsonpCallback,
                success: options.success_callback,
                error: options.error_callback,
                timeout: options.timeout
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        init: init
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

I know we can use JSONP request as require calls but that restricts me to using jsonp, making GET requests and all other features $.ajax offers.

Comment: What does not work in this code? And what does this have to do with require.js?

Comment: Why are you using JSONP instead of plain JSON? Can you post a sample response?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I have updated the question. Whole reason is passing callbacks within requirejs define blocks.

Comment: Pass function references to the `success`, etc, callbacks, rather than strings.

Comment: You are returning init:undefined - that can't help your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/4JGxp/3/) would let you either use a default success callback, or provide an override, using:

```
success: options.successCallback || renderData
```

*(The example uses jsfiddle rest URLs - this fact is unimportant, and stripped out the data object to keep the example short)*

```
define("mymodule", ["jquery"], function($) {
    function renderData() {
        console.log("inside callback");
    }

    function getData(options) {
        $.ajax({
            url: options.apiURL,
            dataType: options.format,
            method: options.method,
            jsonpCallback: options.jsonpCallback,
            success: options.successCallback || renderData,
            error: null,
            timeout: options.timeout
        });
    }

    return {
        getData: getData
    }
});

require(["mymodule"], function(m) {
    console.log(m, m.getData({
        apiURL: "/echo/json/"
    }));
    console.log(m, m.getData({
        successCallback: function() { console.log("outside callback"); },
        apiURL: "/echo/json/"
    }));
});
```

Would print:

```
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/ 200 OK      263ms
Object { getData=getData()} undefined
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/ 200 OK      160ms
Object { getData=getData()} undefined
inside callback
outside callback
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your time. Did you run this code in jsfiddle? If yes can you send me the fiddel url?                                         My understanding is....Since ajax callback will execute in global scope and 'renderData' is defined within 'mymodule', 'inside callback' won't be logged.

Comment: The scope of execution is mostly unimportant as you pass in a local function reference. jQuery will use this function reference that was passed to it, and not try to find a global function. I'll add the fiddle URL.

Comment: I agree on second console.log call where you pass in local function definition. But I guess not for the first console.log call where function reference is passed.

Comment: They are both function references. `renderData` is a named function within the module. `function() { console.log("outside callback"); }` is an anonymous function, but also passed as a function reference. jQuery uses the references, and does not need to look the functions up against any particular scope.